# MapStruct @Mapping whithout source parameter

Tags: java, mapstruct

I need to convert a `dto` to `entity` and the `entity` has a field to populate which doesn't needs any field of the `dto`. Indeed, the `@Mapping` annotation doesn't take any source.

Let's illustrate it with this simple example :

```
public class Employee {
    private String firstName;
    private String customId;
}

public class EmployeeDto {
    private String firstName;
}
```

As you can the field `customId` of the `Employee` entity doesn't exist in the `EmployeeDTO`.

Also, I have the following `formatter`. Obviously, I created an `@CustomIdGenerator` `@interface`

```
public class EmployeeFormatter {
    @CustomIdGenerator
    public static String simulationIdGenerator() {
       return // businessLogic
    }
}
```

And finally my mapper looks like this :

```
@Mapper(uses = EmployeeFormatter.class)
public abstract class EmployeeMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "customId", qualifiedBy = customIdGenerator.class)
    public abstract Employee toEmployee(EmployeeDTO dto);

}
```

But in the generated classes it doesn't work. Do you know if there is any way to use a mapper whithout parameter ?

Thanks for your help ;)

**EDIT :**

Based on the response of @Nikolai Shevchenko the following code works :

```
  @AfterMapping
    void setCustomId(@MappingTarget Employee employee) {
        employee.setCustomId(EmployeeFormatter.customIdGenerator());
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try using expression field in the mapping like this(another way of doing this without source param)

```
@Mapper(uses = EmployeeFormatter.class)
public abstract class EmployeeMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "customId", expression = "java(getCustomId())")
    public abstract Employee toEmployee(EmployeeDTO dto);

    public String getCustomId() {
        return EmployeeFormatter.customIdGenerator();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```java
@Mapper
public abstract class EmployeeMapper {

    @Mapping
    public abstract Employee toEmployee(EmployeeDTO dto);

    @AfterMapping
    void mapCustomId(Employee source, @MappingTarget EmployeeDTO dto) {
        dto.setCustomId(EmployeeFormatter.simulationIdGenerator())
    }
}
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks for the response but based on your response it can be done in a simple way. Check my post edit ;)